# script to try connecting to a cisco router using a different username if first one fails

Tags: bash

i am new to scripting. i am trying my hands on bash.
backgound fo issue: we have hundreds of routers and switches. when the configs were don on the devices, half of them where set up with  one login username and the other half with a different username.
i need to write a script to ssh into all the devices. first part works, as i can get into the device with a username and password. 
I just dont know how to add the second part, to say if you are sshing in and the first username and password fails use the second username and password.

please can someone help me with this.

```
#!/bin/bash

username1="wifi"
cat script/all-devices/devices.log | while read device                     
        do
                ping -i 0.2 -W 1 -c 1 "$device" > /dev/null  
                if [ $? -eq 0 ];
                 then
                 ssh -t -t $username@$device 
         exit 0

        fi
done
```

Comment: you can use `||` to separate two commands, the second command will only execute if the first command exits with an error.

Comment: thanx for the reply, i will def. give it a try. thank you